# Create tag for crafts with metal rings

Tags: discussion

I want to create a tag for crafts with metal rings (ie chain mail), but there are [multiple spellings according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_(armour)) including:

1. mail
2. maille
3. chain mail    --> (chain-mail since tags can't have spaces)
4. chain maille  --> (chain-maille since tags can't have spaces)
5. chainmail
6. chainmaille

Which one should I use? Which one would make the most sense to use? Which one is the most well known and would be the most useful for the tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[chain-mail](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chain-mail) Would be my preference.

The "maille" spelling is not really used widely and the auto-complete will show the tag before they get to the final "le", so it's unlikely to be a problem and if it is, we can create a synonym. I think this is also the UK, or even French spelling, so that makes it even less appropriate. Tags on SE should follow American English spelling conventions.

"Mail" by itself may be ambiguous, so I'd avoid that.

The term definitely has a space in it in common usage, so "chainmail" is also not a great option and, again, typing "chain" will suggest [chain-mail](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chain-mail), so it should be easy to find.

I think there are already [some questions](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/search?q=chain%20mail) about this subject, so please consider adding the tag to them if you do create it. It's worth noting that both of these questions use the spelling I'm proposing for the tag.